# Vector space linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Hi I need a little help about vector space.

Here is the question:

Let E be a vector space over $K$ and $x, y, z$ three vectors in $E$.

Suppose $x$ is a linear combination of $y$ and $z$. We also assume that $x$ is different from zeo.

Show that at least one of the following is true:

1) $y$ is a linear combination of $x$ and $z$.

2) $z$ is a linear combination of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: What have you tried?  Hint:  start by writing your assumption as $\vec x = a\,\vec y +b\, \vec z$  where at least one of $a,b$ is non-zero.  Can you see why we can write that?

Comment: if I suppose a=0 so x  = z? or b=0 so x= y. But the question is I want to show that y is a linear combination of x and z or z linear combination of x and y.

Comment: there are several errors in that.  First of all, it is possible that neither $a$ nor $b$ is $0$.  Secondly, knowing that $a=0$ would not tell you that $\vec x = \vec z$.

Comment: yeah but but if a=0 so ay=0 no??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start from $x=ay+bz$. You know that at least one of $a$ or $b$ is not zero, since $x\ne0$. Suppose $a\ne0$ then we can write $$y=\frac{x-bz}{a}=\frac{1}{a}x-\frac{b}{a}z$$ Then $y$ is a linear combination of $x$ and $z$. Now in a similar fashion, if $a=0$, then $b\ne0$ and you can write
$$z=\frac{x-ay}{b}=\frac{1}{b}x-\frac{a}{b}y$$
The last term is 0 in this case, but that's not important. $z$ is a linear combination of $x$ and $y$.